# Xamarin.UiTest Failed to install Device Agent (ExitCode 143) on physical device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, automated-tests, xamarin.uitest

I am trying to run test on physical iOS device with Mac using Xamarin UiTest .

The configuration in AppInitializer is:

```
return ConfigureApp
    .iOS
    .Debug()
    .InstalledApp("Bundle-Identifier")  
    .DeviceIdentifier("Physical-Device-UUID")
    .StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```

Output show this message:

```
Failed to install DeviceAgent

ExitCode: 134

Reason: tried:   
'/private/var/folders/sq/w4vtqrfd00x6vs4p5ctmlzy00000gn/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/b747d1445588083eee4d1d93a53f3e5b/bin/../Frameworks/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation'
     (no such file),
     '/Library/Frameworks/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation'
     (no such file),
     '/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation'
     (no such file)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle
     ???IBAutolayoutFoundation??? couldn???t be loaded.,
     NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle.,
     NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/IBAutolayoutFoundation,
     NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/IBAutolayoutFoundation,
     0x0109): Library not loaded:
     @rpath/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation
     Reason: tried:
     '/private/var/folders/sq/w4vtqrfd00x6vs4p5ctmlzy00000gn/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/b747d1445588083eee4d1d93a53f3e5b/bin/../Frameworks/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation'
     (no such file),
     '/Library/Frameworks/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation'
     (no such file),
     '/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation'
     (no such file),
     NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework,
     NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn???t be loaded.}}}'  
     Referenced from:
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IBAutolayoutFoundation
     Referenced from:
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IBAutolayoutFoundation
       
         0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81b8d5e5b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff81b636b9d objc_exception_throw + 48
         10  FBDeviceControl                     0x000000010f86a523 __63-[FBiOSDeviceOperator waitForDeviceToBecomeAvailableWithError:]_block_invoke + 67
         11  FBControlCore                       0x000000010f947679 -[FBRunLoopSpinner spinUntilTrue:error:] + 201
         12  FBDeviceControl                     0x000000010f869cca -[FBiOSDeviceOperator waitForDeviceToBecomeAvailableWithError:] + 298
         13  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6b43e2 +[PhysicalDevice withID:] + 240
         14  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6bd290 +[Device withID:] + 118
         15  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6c0647 +[Command deviceFromArgs:] + 130
         16  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6b79b8 +[InstallAppCommand execute:] + 321
         17  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6c3153 +[CLI process:] + 1111
         18  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6ae4c9 main + 121
         19  dyld                                0x00000001148414fe start + 462
         2   Foundation                          0x00007ff81c78c653 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 267
         20  ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
         21  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010f6ad000 __dso_handle + 0
         3   FBControlCore                       0x000000010f97659e -[FBControlCoreFrameworkLoader loadPrivateFrameworksOrAbort] + 622
         4   FBDeviceControl                     0x000000010f86193b __33-[FBDeviceSet primeDeviceManager]_block_invoke + 91
         5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81b5dccc9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
         6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81b5ddec1 _dispatch_once_callout + 20
         7   FBDeviceControl                     0x000000010f8618ad -[FBDeviceSet primeDeviceManager] + 157
         8   FBDeviceControl                     0x000000010f862443 -[FBDeviceSet dvtDeviceWithUDID:] + 67
         9   FBDeviceControl                     0x000000010f864d6b -[FBDevice dvtDevice] + 123 ( )
     
     *** First throw call stack: 2021-11-30 11:59:18.324 iOSDeviceManager[50827:2142641] *** Assertion failure in
     -[FBDeviceControlFrameworkLoader_Xcode loadPrivateFrameworksOrAbort], /Users/moody/git/calabash/FBSimulatorControl/FBControlCore/Utility/FBControlCoreFrameworkLoader.m:84
     2021-11-30 11:59:18.326 iOSDeviceManager[50827:2142641] ***
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception
     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to load private
     frameworks for FBSimulatorControl with error Error
     Domain=com.facebook.FBControlCore Code=0 "Error loading bundle at
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework
     and it was not a linking issue" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error
     loading bundle at
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework
     and it was not a linking issue, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000769470
     {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588
     "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/IBAutolayoutFoundation,
     0x0109): Library not loaded:
     @rpath/AssetCatalogFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AssetCatalogFoundation
    
    libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've already added into `FinishedMethod` `Xamarin.Calabash.Start()` with any result.
Any idea?

Comment: Just confirming that for InstalledApp and DeviceIdentifier that you passed actual values and didn't leave "Bundle-Identifier" and "Physical-Device-UUID" in there?

Comment: Yes, currently the two fields are filled in with the correct values of bundle identifier and the iphone's uuid